# How to avoid Onclick event returning old output along with new output

Tags: javascript, theming, forms

Using db_select got the data(path to csv file) from database, bind it to table(themes) and returned table as output. Each row in the table as hyperlink named "Plot" as shown below.
[image: custom form output]

When user clicks on the plot hyperlink the filename is passed to javascript(located in chart.html) and displayed output content using "file_get_contents"

```
"<a href=# onclick='go(" .$fileName .")'>Plot</a>",
```

For the first time everything is fine as below
[image: Javascript output for first time]

But if user again click on the same plot or on any plot from table, the graphs are displayed one above the other, previous plot graphs are not cleared as shown below image[image: plot hyperlink onclick events displayed one above the other]

I want to overcome multiple graph display. Just display graph only for the latest hyperlink click event.

below is the complete code drupal code.

```
$query1 = db_select('simulation_results', 'sr');
 $query1
     ->fields('sr', array('time','uri_CsvFormat','unique_Id'))
     ->orderBy('sr.time', 'DESC')
     ->condition('sr.user_Id',$user->uid)
     ->condition('sr.unique_Id','%'. $key .'%', 'LIKE')
     ->condition('sr.simulationResult','FlameSpeed');
 $query1 = $query1->extend('TableSort')->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(40);
 $result1 = $query1->execute();
$rows[] =array();
 while($data = $result1->fetchObject())
 {
   $fileName = '"'.file_create_url($data->uri_CsvFormat) . '"';
   $rows[] = array(
   "<a href=" .file_create_url($data->uri_CsvFormat) . ">"."Flamespeed_Results_". $data->unique_Id.'</a>',
   "<div onclick='go(" .$fileName .")'>Plot</div>",
       );     
 }
 $output1 = theme('table',
          array(
            "header" => $header,
            "rows" => $rows,
            "attributes" => array(),
            "sticky" => true, // Table header will be sticky
            "caption" => "",
            "colgroups" => array(),
            "empty" => t("Table has no row!"), 

          )
        ).theme("pager"); 
 $output1 .= "<div ID='CHARTCONTAINER'>" .file_get_contents(drupal_get_path('module', 'flamespeed_tool') . '/chart.html').'</div>';
        return $output1;
```

Please let me know if question is confusing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you already debugged some. So is it a problem with content of response, that each time it contains one more graph? Or is it a problem with JS side, and it appends new graphs instead of replacing them?

Comment: @mOLOT : I am not exactly sure about problem .but i am sure that it is appending new graph instead of replacing them

Comment: @Molot : I tested just the javascript and confirmed the problem is on JS side